# PHP JSON and <script> tag

Tags: php, jquery

I am using PHP to send a json string to jQuery ajax. I am simply using $("#id").html(data.result) to display the html from the fetched page. Now on the fetched page I am looping through MySQL results. I need to run a piece of javascript on each result so I can start a countdown timer for each result.

My problem is that the calling page simply displays the actual javascript script as a string.

```
$row_array['result'] .= '<script>trigger script</script>'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I think that we're going to need more information.  A sample of the returned JSON from your script AND the JavaScript that you're running.  How have you tried to implement it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If part of `data.result` is javascript, it is not executed. Try this:

```
$script = 'alert("this is javascript");';
$html = '<b>blah blah this is html<b>';
$row_array['result'] = json_encode(array('script' => $script, 'html' => $html));
```

and then instead `$("#id").html(data.result)` use:

```
eval(data.result.script)
$("#id").html(data.result.html)
```

Comment: Though using eval is evil... sometimes it is the only way. if you show us your code we might be able to help more...